# how to filter user Id in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created 2 API using node.js and in back end i am using mongodb. I first API i have all the usersid list and i another API i will get single userid in which i need to filter with the first API which contain list of usersid, if userid is matching then i need to send the respected id.

### Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var filtertripSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    filterId : String
});
```

### In this API i will receive single userid

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('filtertrip', filtertripSchema);
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const filter = require('../models/filtertrip');
const expensemaster = require('../models/expensemaster.js'); //here i am call another API which contain list of userid

  router.post('/',  function(req, res, next) {
    filter.create(req.body, function (err, products) {
      if (err) return next(err);
     var Id = products.filterId;
    });
  });
```

### Schema Which contains list of usersid

```
var expensemaster = new mongoose.Schema({
    // expensecategoryname: String,
    expensecategory : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'expensecategory'},
    tripid : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'tripmaster'}
});
```

### Output

```
{
        "_id": "5aba44a56bef1ea0e8817d1e",
        "expensecategory": "5ab89f17f03cfe71f065eda7"
        "tripid": {
            "usersid": [
                "5ab9e0f2a9bcd1050c2f1c92",
                "5ab9e134a9bcd1050c2f1c93",
                "5ab9e169a9bcd1050c2f1c94",
                "5ab9e1a3a9bcd1050c2f1c95",
                "5ab9e2f6a9bcd1050c2f1c97",
                "5aba037057a5b166800c13dd"
            ],
            "_id": "5aba3c9b6bef1ea0e8817d05"
        },
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5aba44a56bef1ea0e8817d22", // I NEED TO SEND THIS ID IF THE USERID IS MATCHING
        "expensecategory": "5ab89f17f03cfe71f065eda7",
        "tripid": {
            "usersid": [
                "5ab9e0f2a9bcd1050c2f1c92",
                "5ab9e134a9bcd1050c2f1c93",
                "5ab9e169a9bcd1050c2f1c94",
                "5ab9e1a3a9bcd1050c2f1c95",
                "5ab9e2f6a9bcd1050c2f1c97",
                "5aba037057a5b166800c13dd"
            ],
            "_id": "5aba3c9b6bef1ea0e8817d05"
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
```

when i get the userid from Another Api i need to call this and filter and the send the _id

please help me with this i am new to node.js

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `middlewares`. In your first API which is used for fetching the userIds pass control to another `middleware` which will filter ids and eventually send back the response.

> Read more about express middlewares at : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html